# how to compact text up arrow in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

How to compact the size of text written upper an arrow in tikz-cd?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {font = \tiny}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\beta, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E)
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale it to any size

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {scale=0.5,yshift=0.2ex}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\beta, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E)
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I personally would rather increase the distance between the columns as suggested by Joule V.

Comment: thank you all. How ever i mean how to reduce the distance between the letters in for all text upper the arrow.

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad Do you really think that there is substantial space between the letters? You could do `\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {xscale=0.5,yshift=0.2ex}}` but this doesn't look good IMHO.

Comment: Dear friend i really mean to reduce the space between the letters.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad How about `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {scale=0.6,yshift=0.2ex}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}\!(\!\beta\!,
\mathrm{id}\!_E\!)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E)
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}` ?

Comment: Yes. But not by using "\!". A general command I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to enlarge the column width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {font = \tiny}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5cm]
0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\beta, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E)
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `tikzcd` for this. Anyway, by reducing the font size and enlarging the column separation you get some result. Below I also show how I'd do it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
0\arrow[r] &
\Hom_R(L, E) \arrow[r,"{\scriptscriptstyle\Hom(\beta, \id_E)}"] &
\Hom_R(N, E) \arrow[r,"{\scriptscriptstyle\Hom(\alpha, \id_E)}"] &
\Hom_R(M, E)
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
0\longrightarrow
\Hom_R(L, E) \xrightarrow{\Hom(\beta, \id_E)}
\Hom_R(N, E) \xrightarrow{\Hom(\alpha, \id_E)}
\Hom_R(M, E)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]